# Brain Tumor Database for CNN?

Tags: dataset, cnn

I'm trying to build a Convolutional Neural Network model to classify and predict a brain tumor based on images. I am looking for a database containing images of brain tumor.

Can someone introduce some medical databases (small one to test or big ones) with links to download?

Answer (score 2):

Some of the followings might be useful:

- [Brain Tumor Image Segmentation Challenge](https://www.virtualskeleton.ch/BRATS/Start2015)
- [Primary Tumor Data Set by UC Irvine Machine Learning Repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/primary+tumor)
- [ncbi.nlm.nih.gov](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gds?term=brain%5BSample%20Source%5D)
- [University of Cyprus](http://www.medinfo.cs.ucy.ac.cy/index.php/downloads/datasets)
- [Brain Tumor Dataset](https://figshare.com/articles/brain_tumor_dataset/1512427)